# Update table with different database and no common fields MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to Update several rows from `DatabaseA.ClientTableA` using `DatabaseB.ClientTableB` given both ids i've tried this so far

```
UPDATE DatabaseA.ClientTableA 
SET DatabaseA.ClientTableA.Field = (SELECT DatabaseB.ClientTableB.Field 
                                    FROM DatabaseB.ClientTableB
                                    WHERE DatabaseB.ClientTableB.ID = 11)
WHERE DatabaseA.ClientTableA.ID = 22
```

But it's not working and phpMyAdmin is not kind enoug to tell me why. Has been a while since I worked with databases and I've been searching around here but only find answers about how to update tables with common fields (using joins)

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**

Here are the tables

| **Database A** |

```
| ClientTableA |    
________________
| id           |
| firstname    |
| Lastname     |
| company      |
| adress1      |
| adress2      |
| state        |
| city         |
| postcode     |
| country      |
| phone        |
| email        |
```

**| Database B |**

```
| ClientTableB |     | emailTable    |
________________     _________________
| id           |     | id            |
| firstname    |     | email         |
| Lastname     |     | pass          |
| company      |
| adress1      |
| adress2      |
| state        |
| city         |
| postcode     |
| country      |
| phone        |
```

**Note:** I pick the email from DatabaseB joining ClientTableB and emailTable by id 
**Note2:** In DatabaseA.ClientTableA all fields are empty except for the id

Comment: If schema is added, then it would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Clear ClientTableA first then do the following:

```
insert into ClientTableA 
(id, firstname, Lastname, company, 
    adress1, adress2, state, city, 
    postcode, country, phone, email)
select b.id, firstname, Lastname, company, 
    adress1, adress2, state, city, 
    postcode, country, phone, email 
from ClientTableB b 
join emailTable e using (id)
```

Alternatively, if you must "UPDATE" for matching "id", do the following:

```
update ClientTableA a, ClientTableB b, emailTable e
set a.first_name = b.first_name, 
    a.Lastname = b.Lastname, ....
    a.email = e.email
where a.id = b.id and b.id = e.id
```